# how to arrange Y axis by factor levels from other variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Take the following `data.frame` example

```
library(ggplot2)
names <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF")
coding <- c("yellow", "blue", "red", "yellow", "blue", "blue")
variable <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6")
values <- c(1,6,12,4,5,7)

data_test <- data.frame(names,coding,variable,values)

ggplot(data_test, aes(variable, reorder(names, -values), size = values, colour = coding)) + 
  geom_point()
```

This is a short example of my original data.

In my data.frame I have 180 names which are associated to 8 levels of a `variable`.
[image: this is where I am, but I need the same color which represent the variable levels to be next to each other]
this is where I am, but I need the same color (which represent the `variable` levels) to be next to each other

Comment: please react to the answers in any sort of form, if it could help in solving your problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

When using `color` in `aes`:
[image]

Giving values to color names in coding column, using `scale_manual_colour`:

```
names <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF")
coding <- c("yellow", "blue", "red", "yellow", "blue", "blue")
variable <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6")
values <- c(1,6,12,4,5,7)

data_test <- data.frame(names,coding,variable,values)

ggplot(data_test, 
       aes(variable, reorder(names, -values),size = values,color=coding)) + 
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('yellow'='yellow','blue'='blue','red'='red'))
```

[image]